# How to filter data frame row by a more decent way in R, given the condition that the cell is a list of lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, geocoding

I have been working on a project that analyzes organizational members' data. One of the approaches is that use the geocoding technique to get each member's location data. I have already gathered the relevant information from Google but there are still some that cannot process properly.

I would like to first filter out those rows that contain nothing inside the list. Yet, due to the nature of the data is a list of lists objects, I cannot find a proper way to filter them all effectively.

The targeted column that I aimed to process:

```
> family[4]
# A tibble: 5,324 x 1
   district        
   <list>          
 1 <named list [2]>
 2 <named list [2]>
 3 <tibble [1 x 2]>
 4 <named list [2]>
 5 <named list [2]>
 6 <tibble [1 x 2]>
 7 <named list [2]>
 8 <named list [2]>
 9 <named list [2]>
10 <named list [2]>
# ... with 5,314 more rows
```

An example on the sturcture of a valid output (I hided most of the information because of sensitivity):

```
> family[4][[1]][[1]]
$results
$results[[1]]
$results[[1]]$address_components
$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]
$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name
[1] "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$short_name
[1] "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$types
$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$types[[1]]
[1] "premise"



$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]]
$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]]$long_name
[1] "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$results[[1]]$geometry$viewport$northeast$lat
[1] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

$results[[1]]$geometry$viewport$northeast$lng
[1] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


$results[[1]]$geometry$viewport$southwest
$results[[1]]$geometry$viewport$southwest$lat
[1] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

$results[[1]]$geometry$viewport$southwest$lng
[1] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx



$results[[2]]$geometry$viewport
$results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$northeast
$results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$northeast$lat
[1] xxx.xx

$results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$northeast$lng
[1] xxx.xx


$results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$southwest
$results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$southwest$lat
[1] xxx.xx

$results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$southwest$lng
[1] xxx.xx




$results[[2]]$place_id
[1] "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$results[[2]]$types
$results[[2]]$types[[1]]
[1] "establishment"

$results[[2]]$types[[2]]
[1] "point_of_interest"




$status
[1] "OK"
```

The invalid output that I would like to fitler out:

```
> family[4][[1]][[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
    lon   lat
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA
```

Questions:

1. What is the coding that can extract those rows with valid outcomes (To keep the <named list [2]> and filter out the <tibble [1 x 2]>) out of the data frame?
2. Is there a way that to extract the only desired attributes from the list of lists into a new column of a data frame?

   Such as the data of lat and lng:

   $results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$northeast$lat
   [1] xxx.xx

   $results[[2]]$geometry$viewport$northeast$lng
   [1] xxx.xx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple MCVE to possibly solve your problem which at the moment doesn't really have one.

It builds a function that returns a logical vector that is then used to index a list:

```
dput(x)    #This is what you should use to illustrate your problem.
#list(list(3, 4), list(x = 5, y = 6))
is_named <- function(x) sapply(x, function(z){ !is.null(names(z))})
is_named(x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
x[is_named(x)]
#---vvvvv---------
[[1]]$x
[1] 5

[[1]]$y
[1] 6
```

You might need to make this recursive. And you might need to add a test for "list-ness".

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I once tried the method of using length() and unlist() to differentiate the valid and invalid output, yet I still cannot find a way apply to the each row separately. In what way should I modify the code to do it once and for all? 

The code that I tried:
> length(unlist(family['district'][[1]][3])) #The invalid output all generate the number of 2 only
[1] 2
> length(unlist(family['district'][[1]][1])) #The example of a valid output 
[1] 60

Comment: @YanNamYIP I don't see how you can get a considered, tested answer unless you a) post a large enough portion of your input data with dput(.) output and b) specify the rule to choose desired and undesired section of your multilevel lists. Why was the third item undesired? Would a test of length be sufficient? Or is a test of depth of the tree needed?   AND DO NOT use comments to address questions. Instead DO use [edit] to modify your question's body.